# Why am I getting access denied to these files?

Tags: visual-studio, compiler-errors, f#

Suddenly I cannot rebuild my project in VS 2017. I get these messages:

`1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4222,5): error MSB3021: Unable to copy file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp\.NETFramework\v4.0\4.4.1.0\FSharp.Core.dll" to "bin\Debug\FSharp.Core.dll". Access to the path 'bin\Debug\FSharp.Core.dll' is denied.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4222,5): error MSB3021: Unable to copy file "H:\Dropbox\BitBucket\VSProjects\Fractal10\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.9.0.1\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll" to "bin\Debug\Newtonsoft.Json.dll". Access to the path 'bin\Debug\Newtonsoft.Json.dll' is denied.`

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you try restarting visual studio?

Comment: I did. I had installed the latest update and now I am afraid that the version I have installed is 15.3.2 and the update was for 15.4.1.

Comment: Try cleaning the solution and building it?

Comment: Yes, several times.

Comment: Was that solution working before? Did you do any package updates?

Comment: Yes, it was working and I was just making changes in the code, rebuilding, and running the code. When I tried to rebuild one more time it suddenly gave me that message.

Comment: Those errors actually mean that these DLLs are being used for another process. Try to close all visual studio instances from task manager. Or restart the machine and try.

Comment: I rebooted and that fixed the problem. Many, many thanks.

Comment: You're welcome and welcome to visual studio 2017. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible causes:

- The app you are trying to build/debug can be running or stuck open
- Tests locking the assemblies could be using them
- post-build steps listed in the properties page of a project could be using them
- while building multiple projects in parallel: another project could have decided to use those `dll` in the output folder for those references
- Visual Studio's F# interactive if set to not shadow copy assemblies could cause it.
- anything else that causes a file to be locked in windows

Comment: If nothing helps, use Process Explorer and search the dll to find who has the lock on it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/

Answer (score 0):

It happened today for me, I had pulled a branch from git repo and the project was not getting compiled or cleaned.

I had to uncheck read-only option for the root directory and the nested files & folders of the root directory.

Go to the folder where the project is, right click on the directory, click properties, Uncheck Read-only option.

[image]