# C++ Visual Studio Access is Denied error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 and am using the Developer Command Prompt to compile and run C++

I wrote a simple program, that has a function that returns Absolute value of a signed int, accepts an input from the user and prints that abs value.

I compiled the code and it worked, ran it once and it worked, then when I typed the program name again to run a second time, I get Access is Denied, unless I recompile, I can only run the program once before I get Access is Denied error...

I didn't have this problem on a simple Hello World program I wrote so not sure what is going on

Any help is appreciated=

my code is simply ---

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

signed int Abs(signed int x);

int main()
{
    signed int n;
    cout << "Enter n to get signed int abs value of: ";
    cin >> n;

    cout << "Signed int: ";
    signed int s = Abs(n);
    cout << s;

    return 0;
}

signed int Abs(signed int x) {
    return (x + (x >> 31)) ^ (x >> 31);
}
```

in my terminal i type

```
cl /EHsc signedint.cpp
```

and then

```
signedint
```

and it works once

when i type

```
signedint
```

a second time i get the error-

```
Access is denied.
```

that is all it says.

Comment: Pust the full error. Access is denied to *what*? Some memory? A file? Which file? See how we have nothing to work with here? Anyway, possible duplicate of [Why am I getting access denied to these files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45898320/why-am-i-getting-access-denied-to-these-files) or many other threads with these search terms

Comment: Why not read about how to ask questions, and then you can post an [mcve].  But my initial guess is: your program didn't actually exit.

Comment: You are likely accessing memory that is out of bounds, commonly referred to as a segfault. Please edit the question with a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that this question can be answered.

Comment: okay updated post w code and exactly what the error says, t just says Access is denied. that is all.

Comment: For my case restarting my system solved the issue. Issue was coming because of Antivirus blocking the execution of .exe.

Answer (score 2):

Solved the problem myself, it was a problem with Norton Antivirus interfering.

To fix this problem, you have to go into settings in Norton Antivirus, Antivirus settings, click on "Scans and Risks", and add your project folder to Exclude from Auto Protect, Sonar and Download Intelligence Detection and Exclude from Scans by clicking the configure button next to those two options.

Comment: Eeek.  Those darn (_stronger expletive replaced_) AV programs interfere all the time... (though it used to be even worse).