# Why is my C program not getting executed although it is a simple program?

Tags: c

Whenever I run my C program, A message is shown in terminal of the visual studio code saying that access is denied and then the antivirus software says there was a virus in my program although my program was simple. My visual studio code is working fine, my windows 10 is fine. But whenever I run the program it happens. The name of the virus is real protect. My compiler is minGw. Is this the problem of compiler os something else. What should I do ?

The program is here

```
#include <stdio.h>
void binarySearch(int arr[], int size, int element)
{
    int found = 0;
    int pos = 0;
    int low, high, mid;
    low = 0;
    high = size - 1;
    while (low <= high)
    {
        mid = (int)((low + high) / 2);
        if (arr[mid] == element)
        {
            found = 1;
            pos = mid;
        }
        else if (arr[mid] < element)
        {
            low = mid + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            high = mid - 1;
        }
    }
    if (found == 1)
    {
        printf("%d Element found at position %d\n",element,pos);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Not Found");
    }
}
int main()
{
    int arr[100] = {1, 7, 18, 99, 100, 124, 128, 255};
    binarySearch(arr, 8, 100);

    return 0;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Md5Ie.png)

Comment: My computer is not infected because All other programming language run fine, all my ides are fine. I have run a scan many times. I have scanned my ide, files, etc. nothing was found it is just that whenever I run C program ...the problem happens. The exact message is Access is denied

Comment: You need to show us the command used to compile the program (the taks.json) so we can see why it isn't creating an executable program.

Comment: ok fine but you can just consider any simple program

Answer (score 0):

No, your PC *isn't* "infected", and no, your program *isn't* "malicious".

But yes, it appears your anti-virus software *is* the culprit:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/47043757/421195
>
> To fix this problem, you have to go into settings in Norton Antivirus, Antivirus settings, click on "Scans and Risks", and add your project folder to Exclude from Auto Protect, Sonar and Download Intelligence Detection and Exclude from Scans by clicking the configure button next to those two options.

Please do the same.

See if you can configure your A/V software to Exclude your project folder - "C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\c programming" - from scanning.  Exactly how to do this depends on your particular A/V software.